# How do I set a const char* after declaration?

Tags: c++, c

```
//v is a random number 0 or 1
const char *str;
//str = 48 + v; //how to set??
```

I tried `memcpy` and `sprintf` and get issues with it being "const char*"

I want to set "str" to 0 or 1 as defined by "v". But it must be of type " const char* "

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do. Can you explain your problem, instead of merely your attempted solution? Perhaps include sample input and corresponding expected output?

Comment: I want to set "str" to 0 or 1 as defined by "v".  But it must be of type "const char*"

Comment: `const char *str = v == 0? "0" : "1";` One day I'll understand why some people shun simple.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes `auto str = v ? "1" : "0";` is even simpler ;)

Comment: `auto str = v ? "49" : "48";` to be correct.

Comment: @FredOverflow good thinking, but even in java it would be 49 and 48 as the `+` operator is on integers.

Comment: Why must `str` be `const char *`?  Note that you can pass a `char *` to a function taking `const char *` without casting.

Comment: MyFunction(const char* str) only says that the function guarantees that it won't modify your string. It does not mean that you can't modify it before or after calling the functions - so you can pass in a non-const char*.

Comment: The nature of StackOverflow is to make things so people can re-use the material.  Specifying this that I am passing this to another function or that I did this in Objective-c was not needed to answer the question... R.MartinhoFernandes answered it so it worked.  I appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is you want to change the value of the const char after you first declare it, correct? While you cannot change the value of the const char* directly, you may be able to change the pointer value to a normal variable.
For example look at this page here: [Constants in C and C++](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html)

This is what you can and cannot do using your pointers to change const values: (Adopted from link above):

```
const int x;      // constant int
x = 2;            // illegal - can't modify x

const int* pX;    // changeable pointer to constant int
*pX = 3;          // illegal -  can't use pX to modify an int
pX = &someOtherIntVar;      // legal - pX can point somewhere else

int* const pY;              // constant pointer to changeable int
*pY = 4;                    // legal - can use pY to modify an int
pY = &someOtherIntVar;      // illegal - can't make pY point anywhere else

const int* const pZ;        // const pointer to const int
*pZ = 5;                    // illegal - can't use pZ to modify an int
pZ = &someOtherIntVar;      // illegal - can't make pZ point anywhere else
```

This also works for chars like you're trying to do.

Comment: well `const int* pX; *pX = 3;` would cause a core dump anyway since pX is not pointing anywhere in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the deal with `const char *`.  It is a pointer to `const char`.  `const char` means that the characters cannot change.  The pointer is not const, so it can change.

When you do this:

```
str = 48 + v;
```

You are attempting to change a pointer to either 48 or 49, depending on what `v` is.  This is nonsensical.  If it compiled, it would point to random memory.  What you want is to change what `str' points to to 0 or 1.

Since it can only point to constant characters, it can only point to something defined as a value, in quotes.  So, for example, it can be set to point to "0", which is a constant character or "1", which is a constant character.  So you can do something like this:

```
str = "0"; // point to a constant character string "0"
if( v )
    str = "1"; // point to a constant character string "1"
```

Note that since `str` points to constant characters, you *cannot* modify what it points to:

```
*str = '1'; // Won't work because you are trying to modify "0" directly.
```